# Process to calculate distance from points to line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, distance, proximity

I am trying to calculate the distance between each point(as seen in the picture below) and its nearest line which is a road.

I have tried to rasterize the data on all the roads and I end up with the rasterized output which can be seen in the second image. I am not sure why the output has those numbers.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two convenient ways to find nearest neighbours in QGIS (point - line, and other geometry combinations).

- The ***NNJoin*** Plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/)
- Since QGIS 3.8, the ***Join Attributes by Nearest*** algorithm (available in the QGIS *Processing Toolbox*)